# Moving to https = Could not find a base address that matches scheme

Tags: wcf

I've created a simple WCF service in an existing web site. I've tested it and all seems well. I've now made the site require https but now when I visit the svc via a browser (or any client) I get --

```
Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding MetadataExchangeHttpsBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]. 

Stack trace is as follows:
[InvalidOperationException: Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding MetadataExchangeHttpsBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].]
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.MakeAbsoluteUri(Uri relativeOrAbsoluteUri, Binding binding, UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses) +12907656
   System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadServiceDescription(ServiceHostBase host, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceElement, Action`1 addBaseAddress, Boolean skipHost) +12905313
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.LoadConfigurationSectionInternal(ConfigLoader configLoader, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceSection) +69
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.ApplyConfiguration() +178
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustServiceHost.ApplyConfiguration() +46
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses) +184
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.InitializeDescription(Type serviceType, UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses) +46
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.InitializeDescription(Object singletonInstance, UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses) +43
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Object singletonInstance, Uri[] baseAddresses) +247
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustServiceHost..ctor(WSTrustServiceContract serviceContract, Uri[] baseAddresses) +72
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustServiceHost..ctor(SecurityTokenServiceConfiguration securityTokenServiceConfiguration, Uri[] baseAddresses) +70
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +280
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +1434
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +52
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +598
```

Comment: what is in the web.config file? where re you hosting the service?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the configuration for the service so that the HTTPS enabled bindings are used. You may want to check out this blog post: http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2008/02/20/wcf-bindings-needed-for-https.aspx

The suggested solution there is to define a custom binding within web.config/app.config and set its security mode to `Transport`:

```
<bindings>
   <webHttpBinding>
     <binding name="webBinding">
       <security mode="Transport" />
     </binding>
   </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Then use this binding in the binding configuration for the endpoint:

```
<endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="..." binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="..." />
```